# jupyter not in PATH after Anaconda3 5.0.1 installation (Windows 7)

Tags: python, path, anaconda, jupyter

I installed Anaconda3-5.0.1 with the Windows x64 installer.
I can launch jupyter from the launch pad but I cannot start or invoke

```
jupyter notebook
```

on the command line (CMD). Examining the PATH I see %PYTHONHOME% in there but %PYTHONHOME% doesn't seem to be set to anything.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to remove %PYTHONHOME% (ignore it). Looked like an Anaconda installation was present. Anaconda3 doesn't seem to care about it but doesn't add the correct path into PATH.

I removed C:\Users\\Anaconda related PATH entries (Anaconda\Scripts) and substituted them by D:\Users\\Anaconda3 (D is correct here because I forced the Anaconda3 installation to go to drive D:). Maybe this is also a cause for the installation quirks.

Answer (score -1):

One good thing about windows (not sure if it exists in other OS's so please excuse me) is that it comes with a nifty GUI editor for you to change your PATH variables.

Just search for 'PATH' in your start bar, from there you can check what variables are on your path and if some are missing, it allows you to add new ones very easily.

Remember to restart CMD once you've done this for all changes to take effect.

Comment: What you are telling here is nothing new and is in no way towards an answer to my question. I would have expected the Anaconda installer having set the PATH correctly.

Comment: And I gave the -1 because entering PATH into the start bar doesn't give the PATH.This is simply wrong information. Entering PATH in a CMD window gives you the PATH besides of looking it up in what you were calling a "nifty GUI editor" while trying to be sarcastic.

Comment: Hi @Krischu, thanks for the feedback, honestly wasn't trying to be sarcastic just trying to help in any way I could. Hope you have a good day.

Comment: actually, if you type PATH in your start bar for the first time you have to follow a slightly different steps. In the window that shows up look for "Environment Variables". There you can enter new or edit existing PATH using a GUI. Once you have done that you should be able to enter PATH straight in your start bar and get to your PATH variables.